# How can you see what functions and variables are currently defined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

There's a function in PHP where you can get a list of the user defined functions that are currently defined, is there something similar in JS?

I'm trying to see a list of functions in Firefox 3, with Firebug enabled.

=/ so far none of the answers work out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var funcs = []; 

for(var prop in window) {
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof window[prop] === 'function') {
    if(window[prop].toString().indexOf("[native code]") === -1) {
      funcs.push(window[prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error when running this in Firefox.. "Operation is not supported" code: "9"

Comment: @codeninja: try this SSCCE at http://jsbin.com/ufoju3/2/.  It works absolutely fine for me in Firefox. @Josh: +1 for the func.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross browser method.  In Internet Explorer, defined variables and functions become members of the `window` object but are non enumerable.  You can check for their existence using `funcName in window`, but you can't enumerate them using a `for...in` statement.

Variables that are defined as properties of the window object *are* enumerable:

```
function someFunc () {} // is not enumerable
window.someOtherFunc = function () {} // is enumerable
```

**EDIT** JScript's implementation is (surprise, surprise) actually wrong, as outlined in [this blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/05/04/414684.aspx).

But I don't think you want to prefix all your variables with `window.`, do you? For a method that will work in some browsers, see [Josh Stodola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526618/how-can-you-see-what-functions-and-variables-are-currently-defined-in-javascript/2526663#2526663).

Comment: I dont need a cross browser answer. I only need to do this in firefox. the above methods return an error

Comment: @codeninja: it looks like Firefox doesn't allow the functions and variables to be enumerable either.

Comment: @codeninja: Josh's code works fine for me in Firefox - SSCCE at http://jsbin.com/ufoju3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Might be overly simple, but if you have Firebug enabled, log `window` to the console. Clicking on it will enumerate all of `window`'s members. That will help you if you need a quick, visual list, but if you're acting upon all of `window`'s members, you'll need to use one of the other methods posted in the comments.

Something like `for(var i in window)` will get you on the right track there.